# Can't find the text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file where it has text `<br><br>` in many rows, I want to find and replace that text, But I couldn't even find this text, Maybe there is some kind of hidden line break between these two `<br>`, Because if I copy paste this text in text editor it automatically show line break

[image]

After 2 hours of googling, I still can't find any solution, I have tried this solution [How to search for newline or linebreak characters in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/370066/how-to-search-for-newline-or-linebreak-characters-in-excel) But didn't work for me. Any idea?

Comment: if you only search for <br> and type that in manually, will it find your <br>'s How about searching for < or >? Alternatively, considered to export everything to .csv and use a program such as notepad++ to do the replacing there, then save and load it back into excel?

Comment: Hi,  yes it finds the one `<br>` and there are too many HTML tags so i can't rely on < or >, I have to find `<br><br>` only. But your CSV idea seems good, I am gonna try that, Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I find the solution, Open the file in https://docs.google.com. It shows the text like this `<br>_x000D_<br>` I don't know what it is but now I can replace this text. https://docs.google.com is best:)

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and mark it as answered in 2 days, so others know you no longer need any help. But glad I could help. :)

Comment: @LPChip I will surely post an answer, But i will do it later with proper screenshots and explanation, Thanks:)